# Reading Text in Matlab

Tags: file-io, matlab-guide

I have a text file which includes both numbers and plenty lines of text. But I just need to read numbers as two seperate Matrix in Matlab. The file is like this:

```
finite element method 
Node Number
1 2 3
1 3 4
2 3 4
coordinates:
10 20
0 20
20 20
14 0
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about the file format? Are the lines "Node Number" and "coordinates:" part of the file, or do you have two separate files? Are there blank lines between the lines containing numbers?

Comment: Hi, First of all, thanks for your attention. All of them are in the same file and there is no blank line between numbers. Actually my problem was somehow solved. The code which I wrote was this. Do you have any better ideas???

Answer (score 0):

---

```
fid=fopen('filename.txt'); %opening the file
while ~feof(fid) %reading up to end of the file

tline = fgetl(fid); %reading line by line
if   strcmp(tline, 'Node Number') %finding the line containing " Node Number"
    break    %stop reading if the "Node Number" was detected
end
end

Nnum =transpose( fscanf(fid,'%d ' , [3 Inf])) %reading the lines after the line which we were stop
                                          % reading would stop as soon
                                          % as the format of reading
                                          % doesn't match anymore


while ~feof(fid) %continuing reading line by line again

tline = fgetl(fid);
if   strcmp(tline, 'coordinates:')%stop when the line "coordinates" 
                                  was detected
    break    
end
end

Coordinate =transpose( fscanf(fid,'%d ' , [2 Inf])) %reading lines after line
                                                "coordinate"
```